# Intuition for distribution of terms of exponential power series

Tags: probability-distributions, power-series, exponential-function, normal-distribution, intuition

One way to express $e^x$ is via a power series:

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

If we plot the first terms of this series for increasing $x$ we observe a distribution of the terms that resembles a normal distribution.

The factorial grows faster than a power, eventually. But is there an intuition or interpretation of the terms' distribution?

[image: first 40 power series terms for x from 0 to 40]

Code for animation: https://gist.github.com/miku/d83be6ec61d05f1fa4ed5b70cf5b59b9

Comment: That's a very nice animation.  It might be easier to make sense of the $y$-axis, however, if we plotted the terms $[x^n/n!]/[e^x]$ to get a "percentage" for each term.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thanks, I'll try to prepare another image - just a bit short on time at the moment.

Comment: no problem, it's not that big of a deal. Great question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing can be recognized as a case of the central limit theorem. The distribution with $P(X=n)=\frac{\frac{x^n}{n!}}{\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{x^n}{n!}}$ converges as $N \to \infty$ to a Poisson(x) distribution. Because of infinite divisibility of the Poisson distribution, the Poisson(x) distribution behaves according to the central limit theorem as $x \to \infty$. By estimating the error you can make the comparison to the normal distribution for finite $N$ and $x$.

You can also make a comparison to a Binomial($N,x/N$), which will also converge to a normal distribution.

Comment: or because $e^{nx} = (e^x)^n$ ? and as $n \to \infty$, the coefficients of $f(x)^n$ (analytic around $x= 0$) converge in some sense to a normal distribution

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, you can also make a comparison to a binomial distribution, which is related to what you said because of the binomial theorem.

Comment: @user1952009 It is actually the same; binomial expansion of $\left ( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \right )^k$ reveals coefficients which are very close to the values of a binomial PMF, which is going to a normal distribution by the CLT (or indeed the older deMoivre-Laplace theorem).

Comment: It isn't what I meant. the OP plotted the Taylor coefficients $c_{k,n}$ of $f(x)^k = e^{kx}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n,k} x^n $ for increasing values of $k$, and by the central limit theorem they converge to a normal distribution (whenever $f(x)$ is analytic on $|x| \le 1$ and its Taylor coefficients $c_n$ are $\ge 0$, so they can be interpreted as $c_k = P(X = k)$, and $c_{k,n} = P(Y_n = k)$, $Y_n = \sum_{j=1}^n X_j$, where $X_j \sim X$ and i.i.d.)

Comment: Ah, yes, what you're pointing out is that this generalizes to generating functions of more complicated positive-integer-valued distributions than just the Bernoulli distribution. Nice point!

Comment: (and $f(x)$ needs not be analytic, all it needs is that $f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n x^n$ for $1-\epsilon < |x| < 1+\epsilon$ and $c_n \ge 0$ i.e. it is analytic on $1-\epsilon < |x| < 1+\epsilon$ and its Laurent coefficients are $\ge 0$)